# Did Krishna say in Bhagavad Gita "I am in every living being"

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

Did Krishna say that he lives in every living entity like animal, tree, human etc.  If yes, then what actually meaning of Krishna living inside all these> Did he live as Atma or as something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Sri Krishna did say that He resides in every being as AtmA :

> 10.20 I am the AtmA residing in the heart of every being. I am the source of their origin, stay and destruction.

Comment: Nice answer, but did Krishna explained with example ? Like he said something directly that I live in animal, trees also? Did he used word "animal" or "tree"?

Comment: @Rishabh 'He said He is present in 'Sarva-Bhuta': So each being like animal and tree are already included. He said in another chapter that His special manifestation among the trees is Asvattha etc and in the Vibhuti-yoga He mentions different kinds of animals also.